# Swift - Attribute string background color on next line

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsattributedstring

I have a label where I wish to show some words on line 1 and some words on line 2. I was able to achieve it by putting "\n" between the strings. Words on line 2 is an attributed string with background color, however the background color starts on line one itself.

Is there a way, I can get background color just on line 2?

***Below is the code:***

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Line 1 Text" ?? "")
let attributesForNonSelectedRow = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor(rgb: 0x707070),NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor:UIColor(rgb: 0xE5E5E5)]
let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: " \n Line 2 Text", attributes: attributesForNonSelectedRow)
attributedString.append(myTitle)
searchTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
searchTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
searchTitleLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple solution: - Just add /n in the line one string - it will solve the issue**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Line 1 Text\n" ?? "")
let attributesForNonSelectedRow = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor(rgb: 0x707070),NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor:UIColor(rgb: 0xE5E5E5)]
let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Line 2 Text", attributes: attributesForNonSelectedRow)
attributedString.append(myTitle)
searchTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
searchTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
searchTitleLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Solution via Constraints:**

Why don't you just try to set the constraints for the label by providing Leading, Top and Height constraints, you can achieve it..

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this question. All I had to do was put "\n" at the back of line 1 instead of in the front of line 2 and that fixed the background color issue.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Line 1 Text \n" ?? "")
let attributesForNonSelectedRow = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor(rgb: 0x707070),NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor:UIColor(rgb: 0xE5E5E5)]
let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Line 2 Text", attributes: attributesForNonSelectedRow)
attributedString.append(myTitle)
searchTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
searchTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
searchTitleLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```